# Is it possible to have two access to each other's fields without making one of static?

Tags: c#, class, field, instance

Sorry if my question seems confusing. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class2 class2;
    public int i;

    public Class1(Class2 class2, int i)
    {
        this.class2 = class2;
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class1 class1;
    public int i;

    public Class2(Class1 class1, int i)
    {
        this.class1 = class1;
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public class Run1
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1(c2,1); // Obviously doesn't work. Since it is not declared
    Class2 c2 = new Class2(c1,2);
}
```

My goal for c1 to have access to c2.i and c2 to have access to c1.i

Comment: Are they required to be passed into the constructor? Or can you set the properties after they are instantiated?

Comment: The int value is not required to be passed into the constructor.

Comment: I was referring to the instances of Class1 and Class2, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but the way you are doing it is anything but recommended. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Comment: I think you are showing a simplified example to ask the question - but it is likely you just need to use a third class containing the Class1 and Class2 instances.

Comment: Your fields are public, so why don't you just use: `var c1 = new Class1(null, 1); var c2 = new Class2(c1, 2); c1.class2 = c2;`?

Comment: @EmilioLucasCeroleni The link was what I was looking for. I was having all the problems mentioned.

Comment: @Liam This sort of tightly coupled relationship between two classes is usually a sign of bad design and highly problematic when it comes to (for instance) serialization. Why does each class need to know about the other? It would be far healthier to decouple the relationship by other means. Maybe events might be a good candidate, but without knowing what you're really trying to do, there's not enough info to write a helpful answer. The existing answers are just helping you to perpetuate the rot...

Comment: It is my personal opinion (one which I have found to be useful in almost all circumstances), that when you come across two classes which seem to benefit from referencing each other, there is usually a better solution involving a third “parent” class which interacts with both “child” classes, and understands the ways in which those child classes should communicate. That pattern also usually benefits from a sub-pub or callback pattern in the case that the children need to communicate back to the parent, thus not *requiring* an explicit connection to the parent class. Can be achieved functionally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different solutions to this depending on your need.

First, removing the initialization dependency and setting the properties later:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int i;
    public Class2 class2;

    public Class1(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int i;
    public Class1 class1;

    public Class2(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new Class1(1);
        var c2 = new Class2(2);
        c1.class2 = c2;
        c2.class1 = c1;
    }
}
```

Next is having one class created as a child object of the other when the parent is created:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int i;
    public Class2 class2;

    public Class1(int i1, int i2)
    {
        this.i = i1;
        class2 = new Class2(i2, this);
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int i;
    public Class1 class1;

    public Class2(int i, Class1 class1)
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.class1 = class1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new Class1(1, 2);
        var c2 = c1.class2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution worked for my problem. No issues so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend something along these lines if you just need to "group" the instances together to access each other.

```
public class Class1
{
    public int x;
    public Class1(int a)    {x = a;}
}
public class Class2
{
    public int y;
    public Class2(int a)    {y = a;}
}
public class Pair
{
    public Class1 u;
    public Class2 v;
    public Pair(Class1 a_u, Class2 a_v) {u = a_u; v = a_v;}
    public int Function() { return u.x + v.y; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pair z = new Pair(new Class1(1), new Class2(2));
        int w = z.Function();
    }
}
```